# Why this codeblock is creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was playing with a fiddle earlier today while trying to answer a question and found a confusing thing. Being a JS newbie I am not being able to debug whats going wrong myself. I even tried to check the source0 of `$.fn.show` in jQuery source but couldn't figure out whats going wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id='dataBox'/>
<input type='button' value='toggle' id='toggleButton' />​
```

**jQuery code:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var _oldShow = $.fn.show;
    $.fn.show = function (speed, oldCallback) {
        return $(this).each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                newCallback = function () {

                    if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)) {
                        oldCallback.apply(obj);
                    }
                    obj.trigger('afterShow');
                };
            obj.trigger('beforeShow');
            if(speed)    
                _oldShow.apply(obj, [speed,newCallback]);
            else    
                _oldShow.apply(obj, [newCallback]);
        });
    }
});


$('#dataBox').bind('beforeShow', function () {
        alert('beforeShow');
    });


$('#toggleButton').click(function(){
        $('#dataBox').show();
});
```

The problem is for some mistake that I did, is causing this line to execute infinite number of times
     obj.trigger('beforeShow');

and hence the `alert` in this block

```
 $('#dataBox').bind('beforeShow', function () {
    alert('beforeShow');
 });
```

seems not to stop.

Irrespect of what I am trying to do or if this can be done any other way, can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here. I have been trying for several hours but couldn't figure out.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/evdpj/)

Comment: One suggestion for easier debugging. Use the statement `debugger;` instead of `alert('beforeShow');` in your bind method. This will put a break point there so that you can see the stack trace in the debugger.

Comment: @BrantOlsen `debugger;` works with Visual Studio i guess what if the OP is using php or no server side for instance, `console.log` would be a better suggestion

Comment: @3nigma It also works with Chrome and Firebug.

Comment: @BrantOlsen that i didnt know, tnx for sharing

Comment: @BrantOlsen Thanks for the `debugger;` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that at some point jQuery calls the `$.fn.show` from within itself and that creates the infinite loop. So the proper way to prevent that is to do some argument checking like follows:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    var _oldShow = $.fn.show;
    $.fn.show = function(speed, easing, oldCallback) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            duration = args[0] || 0,
            easing = 'linear',
            callback = function() {},
            callbackArgIndex = 1;

        // jQuery recursively calls show sometimes; we shouldn't
        //  handle such situations. Pass it to original show method.    
        if (!this.selector) {
            _oldShow.apply(this, args);
            return this;
        }

        if (args.length === 2) {
            if ($.isFunction(args[1])) {
                callback = args[1];
                callbackArgIndex = 1;
            }
            else {
                easing = args[1];
            }
        }
        else if (args.length === 3) {
            easing = args[1];
            callback = args[2];
            callbackArgIndex = 2;
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this),
                oldCallback = callback,
                newCallback = function() {

                    if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)) {
                        oldCallback.apply(obj);
                    }
                    obj.trigger('afterShow');
                };
            obj.trigger('beforeShow');
            args[0] = duration;

            if (callback) {
                args[callbackArgIndex] = newCallback;
            }
            else {
                args.push(callback);
            }

            _oldShow.apply(obj, args);


        });
    }
});


$('#dataBox').bind('beforeShow afterShow', function(e) {
    alert(e.type);
});


$('#toggleButton').click(function() {

    $('#dataBox').show();

});​
```

This works fine and the events are fired properly.

The block which is preventing the infinite loop is this

```
if (!this.selector) {
      _oldShow.apply(this, args);
      return this;
}
```

What this is doing is, calling the original function and returning in cases jQuery calls `$.fn.show` multiple times(jQuery seems to be doing so for some reason).

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/evdpj/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at this section

```
    if(speed)    
        _oldShow.apply(obj, [speed,newCallback]);
    else    
        _oldShow.apply(obj, [newCallback]);

    });
```

`_oldShow` is assigned as `$.fn.show;` earlier, and `.apply()` calls a function with arguments as an array and the ability to set the context of `this`. [(see here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

So, at the end of the function, we always end up calling the function again, infinitely triggering beforeShow.

Comment: If you look at code carefully you can see that in it function $.fn.show just  wrapped with another function which calls the original one - not itself.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't understand what you're trying to say. `_oldShow` is equal to the anonymous function that contains the function that contains the if block above, calling itself infinitely.

Comment: in order to check you theory you may alert something like this: "alert($.fn.show === _oldShow);". Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D9vP6/ if you do so you can see that functions are differ.

Comment: @Dmitry You still don't make any sense. All you proved is that the function is calling itself into infinite recursion, which was what my answer was explaining.

Comment: But I am making a copy of `$.fn.show` in the very first line `var _oldShow = $.fn.show;` does it only make a reference to `$.fn.show` and not a duplicate copy of the function. You seem to be right. But then how can I make a copy of `$.fn.show` and use that later?

Comment: @Joy what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: My intention was to modify '$.fn.show/$.fn.hide' to fire event before and after `show/hide`. Maybe that can be done in other easier way. But I would be glad to know whats wrong with this and maybe how can I fix this. Would be a good thing to learn I think. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Joy you're close to what you want, but I'm assuming this was originally some kind of animation function?

Comment: yeah, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/evdpj/3/ click until it echoes the `_oldShow` several times, it's actually the original `$.fn.show` being called all the times. Used the development version of jQuery to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Look into show function code(its in alert):
http://jsfiddle.net/D9vP6/4/

It seemed to call inself under some condition in order to normalyze argument. After redefining this function you receive infinite recursion.

To avoid such behaviour you should have all this normalizing in you code and do not trigger event under some conditions.

Comment: It's actually the original `$.fn.show`. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/evdpj/3/ +1 for this.

Comment: @Joy, yes it is and it try to call itself which is actually isn't itself anymore, as it was redefined. So it calls you function istead, which call original and so on.